# How to create a "rebuild" task in gulp?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
  // Build, generate files...
});

gulp.task('clear', function () {
  // Delete generated files.
});

gulp.task('rebuild', function () {
  // First: clear
  // Then: build
});
```

In most case, "build" task doesn't need previous generated files to be removed (which slows the build process).

But there is times when I want to run "clear" and "build" task in one command:

Of course "rebuild" task depends on "clear" and "build", but if I use dependency hint like

```
gulp.task('rebuild', ['clear', 'build']);
```

the two tasks run asynchronously, which results in unexpected problem!

---

The easy way to solve this problem is run:

```
gulp clear
gulp build
```

but a single command

```
gulp rebuild
```

is easier, right? :P

By the way, `gulp.series()` has been deprecated...

Comment: What about `gulp <task> --rebuild`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not perfect but should work. Extract build task into a function. Then excute in the build and rebuild tasks.

```
var build = function() {
    return gulp.src().concat();
}

gulp.task('build', function () {
  return build();
});

gulp.task('clear', function () {
  // Delete generated files.
});

gulp.task('rebuild', ['clear'], function () {
  return build();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution isn't via Gulp as you requested, but NPM may be a better choice since you probably have NPM right there handy. All you're trying to do is save a few keystrokes.

Add an NPM script "rg" (rebuild-gulp) which does what you need:

```
"scripts": {
  "rg": "gulp clear && gulp build"
}
```

Invoke with `npm run rg`